# How to use jQuery UI Datepicker as a Django Widget?

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-widget

Some of my Django 1.3 models have DateField properties. When a form is generated, I'd like to use the jQuery UI Datepicker instead of a plain text field. I understand that I could create new widgets but I don't understand how. In addition, I am not sure if anything like this has already been done for Django (I googled it, no chance).

How to create a Django Widget that I can reuse across multiple models (and page) for the jQuery UI Datepicker?

Answer (score 11):

JQueryUI has a very good date UI picker.
You can get it here: http://jqueryui.com

Say for example you have the following form:

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
   myDate = forms.DateField()
```

From here you want to bind the JQuery date widget to your field from within your template.

I am assuming here you are passing the `DateForm` to your template and your path(s) to JQuery are correct.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#id_myDate" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="id_myDate"></p>

</body>
```

Please note that `myDate` is preceded by `id_`. Django does this transparently so make sure you match it as such: `id_myDate`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: can you tell me if i am using a model form instead of <input type="text" id="id_mydate">,how to render the datepicker

Comment: I tried this, and I also had to add name="myDate" to get it to work.

Comment: @user2086641 I think you should exclude the myDate field from the model form (google it, it's easy) and place it manually in the page like the answer suggests.

Comment: @dave: FYI, your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You should look on [DateInput](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py#L398) - you'll need to inherit your widget from it. Also look on [admin widgets](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L26) - there are some JS appended. So take DateInput, add some JS and you're done.