# django admin datetime picker not showing up

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model defined as such in my models.py:

```
class xx(models.Model):
    ...
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of birth", blank=True)
    ...
```

It is not showing up in my admin interface using the django datetime picker. It was showing up initially as desired, but then I overrode the change_form.html for writing some js, and that's screwed it up I guess. Commenting out the js also doesn't help so I'm not able to narrow down the issue. Any leads?

Comment: The same exact thing has happened to me, right after trying to add tinymce to the admin interface. I still havn't worked it out.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around it by overriding the widget in the Meta class:

```
class Meta:
    ...
    widgets = {'dob': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),}
    ...
```

This helped: [How to use a JQuery Datepicker with the Django template language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106454/how-to-use-a-jquery-datepicker-with-the-django-template-language)

However, I don't understand clearly as to why I had to override the widget? How was the default behavior effected?